# Calculated values is ALWAYS 0 and I don't know why

Tags: c#

I'm taking a intro to programming class and i'm having issues with an assignment. The code is supposed to calculate a value but the answer I always get is 0. Not sure what i'm doing wrong but hoping someone can help me out and explain to me where my error is?
Any tips for beginners?

```
class changeValue
{
    //Create a class called changeValue that declares 2 integer class variables:  value1 and 
    //  value2.  These should be declared as public and you should not use automatic properties 
    // to declare them. 
    private int _value1;
    private int _value2;

    public int Value1
    {
        get
        {
            return _value1;
        }//end get
        set
        {
            _value1 = value;
        }//end set
    }

    public int Value2
    {
        get
        {
            return _value2;
        }//end get
        set
        {
            _value2 = value;
        }//end set
    }
    public changeValue(int val1, int val2)
    {
        //here is the constructor where you code the if statements
        int value1 = val1;
        int value2 = val2;

        if (value1 > 5)
        { 
            value1 = val1; 
        }
        if (val1 <= 5)
        {
            value1 = (val1+val2);
        }
        if (val2 < 10)
        {
            value2 = (val2 * val2 + 5);
        }
        if (val2 >= 10)
        {
            value2 = val2;
        }
    }

    public void printit()
    {
        //here is the printit method used to print the results
       Console.WriteLine("The calculated value is:" + (Value1 * Value2));

    }
}
class assignment3
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //declare the local val1 and val2 integer variables
        int val1;
        int val2;    

        //prompt the user for input of two integers
        //don’t forget to convert from the string input to integer
        Console.Write("Enter an integer value: "); //obtain user input
        val1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Enter a second integer value: "); //obtain user input
        val2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        //instantiate a changeValue object here
        changeValue myValue = new changeValue(val1,val2);

        myValue.printit();//call the object method printit here
    }
}
```

}

Thank to all that help, this class is not easy.

Comment: have you tried to **debug** it?

Comment: What input are you using? Can you give us any other information?

Comment: You are never setting anything into the Value1 and Value2 properties or their private fields. You are only assigning values to private fields within the constructor.

Comment: yes, but I'm not familiar at all with the output from debug

Answer (score 2):

In you changeValue method you're defining local variables that aren't using your fields

```
int value1 = val1;
int value2 = val2;
```

=>

```
_value1 = val1;
_value2 = val2;
```

Answer (score 0):

In changeValue, you have local variables value1 and value2.  Your class has variables _value1 and _value2.  Those names are different, obviously.  Do you want to be changing the local variables or the class variables?

I should add that you're doing C# properties, so you also have properties Value1 and Value2, which are also different than your local variables value1 and value2 (because of the capital V)

Comment: "Do you want to be changing the local variables or the class variables?" Honestly, I have no idea.

Comment: It looks to me like your assignment is to write a class that holds two values and can print the sum.  If that's the case, then you want to store the values in your class properties, Value1 and Value2 (with capital V).   The local variables value1 and value2 only exist while the constructor changeValue is running, and then they go away.  Those local variables don't stick around to be used by printIt.  If you look closely, your printIt function isn't even trying to use those local variables.  It is using the properties Value1 and Value2 (with capital V).